# Trigger needs to fire only when column value is today's date

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date, triggers

I want to apply the trigger in database when column_value match the particular scenario like

In `goal` table there are fields like goal, status, start_Date, end_Date

Now I want to change the status of goal. When user enter his/her goal, he/she filled end_Date. Now I want to change the status of goal when end_Date matched to current Date

Example:-

```
+------+--------+--------------+-------------+
| GOAL | STATUS | START_DATE   | END_DATE    |
+------+--------+--------------+-------------+
|    1 | Active | 2017-07-03   | 2017-07-09  |
+------+--------+------------+---------------+
```

When END_DATE equals to current Date, then I want to change status 'Active' to 'Finished'

I hope I am able to understand my question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add script with what you have got so far, we will help improve it

Comment: Triggers fire when an update/insert/delete is actioned. I think you need to look at events or cron(for linux).

Comment: @BHouse Want to do with database so need of script

Comment: @P.Salmon So I can add check while inserting

Comment: You can't control when the trigger will fire, but you can control what it will do. Simply add that check to your trigger logic.

Comment: How can I implement the logic ?

Comment: You changed the question..You cannot expect a trigger to do this - see my previous comment.

Comment: Actually I want to say the same. but unable to create table then I copied table from the listed answer

Answer (score 0):

Body of an oracle table level trigger would look like this...

```
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING and (:new.end_date = sysdate) THEN
    :NEW.goal_status := desired_value;
  ELSIF UPDATING AND (:new.end_date = sysdate) then
    :NEW.goal_status := desired_value;
  END IF;
End;
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic for this is

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS TB;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER TB BEFORE INSERT ON T
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

 IF NEW.START_DT = DATE(NOW()) THEN
    SET NEW.STATUS = 'YES' ;
 end if;
END //
DELIMITER ;

  use sandbox;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T(GOAL INT, STATUS VARCHAR(3), START_DT DATE,END_DATE DATE);
mysql> TRUNCATE TABLE T;INSERT INTO T VALUES(1,NULL,'2017-07-06','2017-07-06');SELECT * FROM T;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.73 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

+------+--------+------------+------------+
| GOAL | STATUS | START_DT   | END_DATE   |
+------+--------+------------+------------+
|    1 | YES    | 2017-07-06 | 2017-07-06 |
+------+--------+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```